# Double slash in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Why the bash console accept "/bin//bash" instead of "/bin/bash"? The path "/bin//bash" doesn't exist, but when I enter the double slash, a new bash session is opened.

Comment: [Check this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

Comment: so, what is the question? It doesn´t matter how many slashes you put.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of a question previously asked and answered on a different StackExchange site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file

Comment: Also, this isn't a bash-specific behavior -- it applies to *all* UNIX applications, making the tagging a bit off-base. (That said, POSIX allows implementation-defined behavior in the case of paths starting with `//`; thus, `//bin/bash` is allowed to do something different than what `/bin/bash` does; fairly few systems implement such extensions, however).

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of file parsing done by the open syscall..  The open call  allocates a file descriptor, then parses the path components using filesystem related calls-- `/bin/////bash` will also do what you show.  This is because by POSIX rules one or more contiguous `/` characters are defined to delimit a valid pathname.  The people who wrote bash know this, so `fnmatch` behaves the way the standard says:

See [POSIX.1-2017 #3.271 "Pathname"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271):

> Multiple successive `<slash>` characters are considered to be the same as one 
>   `<slash>`, except for the case of exactly two leading `<slash>` characters.

Comment: You can pass a path with more than one `/` as a separator to the `open()` syscall, so this behavior would still exist even if fnmatch() were not in use, making calling it a "result" of the use of fnmatch() a bit questionable.

Comment: bash uses fnmatch, I believe.  glob  does similar work for other shells and bash.  'So what does open use to resolve pathnames into a file inode number?'  is your question/point, really.  I do not know.  I believe it is filesystem (therefore driver) dependent.  ftw, nftw, scandir and other functions read directories as well.  What do they call?

Comment: Yes -- the open() syscall is implemented by the filesystem; the filesystem's behavior is specified by POSIX.

Comment: And actually -- if `fnmatch()` stripped extra slashes out of filenames before returning them in its results, it would break filesystems like AFS, for which double-slashes have special meaning (as POSIX allows them to do).

Comment: FWIW: @charlesduffy I said nothing about stripping out characters.  I simply said it behaves according to POSIX standards.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Sure, but it says "as a result of file matching". That's the part that's blatantly untrue; the same behavior would exist with no file matching at all performed.

Comment: Removed file matching.  Based on 'Solaris Internals' McDougall and Mauro p660-661. Used their term 'parse'.